# Search() adding in extra parentheses in RegExp - Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm trying to match plural cases with a regexp using search. My regexp is:

`var r = new RegExp(actualArr[i] + '(e?s)?(\>|$)', 'gi')`

and I'm using search as such:

`if(expected.search(r) !== -1){...}`

when I run the regexp in the console with search, it works just fine, but through my app I get the following error:

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(Squat(e?s)?/: Unterminated group`

When I print out my regexp, I get this:

`/Squat(e?s)?(>|$)/gi`

Why is an extra `(` being added on here? What am I missing?

here's the full block of code:

```
let matchPlural = function(actual,expected) {
        let actualArr = actual.split(" ");
        for(let i = 0; i < actualArr.length; i++){
            let r = new RegExp(actualArr[i] + '(e?s)?(\>|$)', 'gi')
            if (expected.search(r) !== -1){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

As a side note, I'm developing in AngularJS, I don't think that should affect anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `actualArr[i]` which I suppose is an array of words must start with a parenthesis. As Parenthesis defines a group in regular expression, this one becomes invalid when you concat the word with `'(e?s)?(\>|$)', 'gi')`

Run the following snippet and look at console result

```js
var applyFix = true;

let matchPlural = function(actual,expected) {
    let actualArr = actual.split(" ");
    for(let i = 0; i < actualArr.length; i++) {

      let word = actualArr[i];
      
      // Remove any non-word character
      if(applyFix) word = word.replace(/\W/g,'');

      let r = new RegExp(word + '(e?s)?(\>|$)', 'gi')
      if (expected.search(r) !== -1){
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(matchPlural('Foo Dummy Squat','Hello Squate'))
console.log(matchPlural('Foo Dummy Squat','Hello Squates'))
console.log(matchPlural('Foo Dummy Squat','Hello Squats'))
console.log(matchPlural('Foo Dummy (Squat','Hello Squats'))

// Disable fix
applyFix = false

console.log(matchPlural('Foo Dummy (Squat','Hello Squats'))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks... I feel stupid, I made an assumption it was failing on the first item. This works great, I only had to add a check for if `word` is an empty string to then skip the regex compare portion.

Thanks again!